# Wireframe cube rendering blank in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I'm creating a voxel game and want to highlight the block that the camera is pointing at with a wireframe model. However, I can't for the life of me figure out why this isn't showing up. I've set the position of the model to a static location.

renderer:

```
constexpr std::array<float, 72> VERTICES =
{
    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,

    1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,

    0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,

    0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,

    0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,

    1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f
};

constexpr std::array<int, 24> INDICES =
{
    0, 1, 2, 3,
    4, 5, 6, 7,
    8, 9, 10, 11,
    12, 13, 14, 15,
    16, 17, 18, 19,
    20, 21, 22, 23
};

SelectedBlockRenderer::SelectedBlockRenderer():
    should_render(false),
    shader("shader/selectedBlockVertexShader.txt", "shader/selectedBlockFragmentShader.txt")
{
    shader.set_uniforms({"position", "projectionView"});

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao_id);
    glGenBuffers(1, &v_buffer_id);
    glGenBuffers(1, &i_buffer_id);

    glBindVertexArray(vao_id);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, v_buffer_id);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(VERTICES), &VERTICES[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, nullptr);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, i_buffer_id);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(INDICES), &INDICES[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}

SelectedBlockRenderer::~SelectedBlockRenderer()
{

}

void SelectedBlockRenderer::render(const Display& display, const Camera& camera)
{
    if (!should_render) return;

    glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);

    glLineWidth(10.0f);

    glm::mat4 projection_view = display.get_projection_matrix() * camera.get_view();

    shader.activate();
    shader.load_uniform("projectionView", projection_view);
    shader.load_uniform("position", glm::vec3(x, y, z));

    glBindVertexArray(vao_id);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glDrawElements(GL_QUADS, INDICES.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, nullptr);

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);

    shader.deactivate();

    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);
}

void SelectedBlockRenderer::free()
{
    shader.free();

    glDeleteBuffers(1, &v_buffer_id);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &i_buffer_id);
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &vao_id);
}
```

Shader code:

```
#version 400 core

layout(location = 0) in vec3 vertex;

uniform mat4 projectionView;
uniform vec3 position;

void main () {
    gl_Position = projectionView * vec4(position, 1.0);
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
#version 400 core

out vec4 fragment;

void main () {
    fragment = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

I know that the Shader class works because I've used it in all of the other renderers. Here's the relevant main.cpp code:

```
void main () {
    SelectedBlockRenderer sb_renderer;

    while(!display.closed) {
        if (timer.update_requested) {
            //update display and camera
            sb_renderer.render(display, camera);
        }
    }

    sb_renderer.free();
}
```

If any other code is required I'd be happy to share it.
I must be missing something really obvious. If anyone has any idea I'd love to hear it.

Comment: `position` is a uniform variable. You've to use the vertex coordinate attribute `vertex`,  so it has to be `gl_Position = projectionView * vec4(vertex, 1.0);`

Comment: That's it!! aaarrrrggggg... I'm such an idiot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`position` is a uniform variable. The name of the vertex coordinate attribute is `vertex`.

The position of the current vertex ([`gl_Position`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/gl_Position.xhtml)) should be set by a function of the vertex coordinate. e.g.:

```c
gl_Position = projectionView * vec4(vertex, 1.0);
```

or

```c
gl_Position = projectionView * vec4(vertex + position, 1.0);
```